# Brave browser does not automatically load newest version of page

Tags: brave-browser

Almost every time I open a site, it loads the previously viewed version, not the latest one. A news site might load the news from 2 days ago instead of today's most recent news. I have to manually reload the site.

Chrome and DuckDuckGo don't have this problem, but I prefer Brave's privacy.
Once in a while it will refresh on its own. No rhyme or reason I can see.
How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your browser URL type: `brave://settings/clearBrowserData`, and clear all the cache. Make sure you select *all time*

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache will do it.

- Press `3 dots` at the bottom right
- Press `History`
- Press `Clear Browsing Data`
- Ensure that `Cached Images and Files` is ticked.  You can untick other items if you want.
- Press `Clear Data`